How to skip/do_not_probe certain pci vendor:device hardening (intel_me and amd_psr)
According to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/pci/probe.c
this code snippet
if (bridge->vendor == PCI_VENDOR_ID_DEC && bridge->device == 0x0001) return;
where bridge->device == pci_device_hex_code
example, intel mei is 8086:2490, the code would be
if (bridge->vendor == 0x8086 && bridge->device == 0x2490) return;
my doubt is if that is right? after recompiling kernel the lspci -nnk should not probe/prefetch intel_me pci device.
Any ideas? this could be the pattern of hardener linux kernel with a loop for/while/do_while ...
Thx
